Why is my kitchen flooding from the dishwasher after the shower in the bathroom next to the kitchen is used?
The dishwasher has been previously run successfully. It has drained & dried the dishes. A person takes a shower in the bathroom next door to the kitchen. Minutes later, the kitchen is flooded with water coming out the bottom of the dishwasher door. We believe this only happens when the dishwasher door is tightly latched, but not when it’s unlatched and/or slightly ajar.

It shouldn't be possible for wastewater to back up into a properly plumbed dishwasher in the first place - do you have an air gap or a high loop? Is water backing up into any other fixture? What's downstream of what?

There are two separate, but related, issues here:

Partial Clog

This is the main problem. You have a partial clog in the main sewer line, downstream of both the kitchen and bathroom. That could be accumulated grease (kitchen) + lint (laundry) + hair (bathroom). Or it could be roots. Or some combination. It is probably a good ways down the line because it only happens when you combine dishwasher (several gallons) + shower (varies depending on the person) but not just one of those by itself. That may be possible to fix with chemicals (but I find those work better on a total or near-total clog), air pressure or the old standby, the power snake (a hand snake isn't likely to do much as this is far down the line).

Dishwasher Drainage

Water comes out the lowest spot before the clog. In my house that is usually the basement floor drain. But sometimes it is a toilet or a sink or, in your case, the dishwasher.
However, a dishwasher is supposed to have an air gap above the trap to prevent backflow of this type. The backflow will still happen, but it will instead come up through the kitchen sink, which isn't great but is generally a little better.
There are two ways of providing this air gap. The traditional one is to have the dishwasher drain hose go up to an actual "air gap" installed in a hole at the back of the sink with a second hose going down to the sink trap. You don't have that. The second way, which you should have but it was either not installed correctly or has fallen down, is a high hose loop. The dishwasher drains into a hose which loops up to just under the counter and then goes down to the sink trap. A high hose loop has the advantage of no air gap that could leak or just get yucky, but it has the disadvantage that the hose can fall down unless it is secured well - which is a fairly common occurrence.
So check under the sink. Fix the hose loop problem. If you're not sure, or it isn't obvious what to do, upload a picture.
